# View doesn't change though scope variable has changed in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, view, scope

I'm stuck with this for the whole day.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in usernames">
        <td>{{x.username}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type='button' ng-click='sendMessage()'>Send  Message</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" ng-click="deleteUser()">Delete User</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I press *"Send Message"*, controller is ignited successfully.

```
$scope.sendMessage = function () {
    $scope.content_in = '<form novalidate>'
        +'<label>Message: &nbsp</label> <input type="text" ng-model="message"/><br><br>'
        +'<button id="mybutton" style="width:75px" ng-click="send()">Send</button>'
        +'<input id="mycancel" style="width:75px" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>'
        +'</form>';
}
```

I'm simply trying to update my page with a message form which will be placed in `content_in` variable. But the changes are not reflected in the view.

I also included:

```
$scope.$watch('content_in', function () {
    alert('hey, content_in has changed!');
});
```

in the controller, and I'm confident that the changes are made in controller.
How can I make the view reflect the changes?

Comment: I haven't noticed any usage of `content_in` in your HTML. Please provide some relevant markup or, it would be the best, a jsFiddle or plunker. Thx!

Comment: Try to use $scope.$apply

Comment: Couldn't you use `ngShow` `ngIf` or `ngBindHtml` instead?

Comment: $scope.$apply - not recommended to be used to force apply.... Please provide more code to see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach

```
 myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope,  $compile, myService) 
{
    $scope.sendMessage = function () {
        var content_in = '<form novalidate>'
        +'<label>Message: &nbsp</label> <input type="text" ng-model="message" /><br><br>'
        +'<button id="mybutton" style="width:75px" ng-click="send()">Send</button>'
        +'<input id="mycancel" style="width:75px" type="reset" value="Cancel" />'
        +'</form>';
        var element = angular.element(document.querySelector("#myDiv"));
        element.empty();
        element.append(content_in);
        $compile(element.contents())($scope);
    }
});
```

In your design page add this div

```
<div id="myDiv">
```